# Android isLoggable returns erratic results?

Tags: android, logging

I have a custom sync adapter class, and in it's onPerformSync() method, I'm attempting to write several debug log messages, and I'm making use of Android's isLoggable() in conjunction with `setprop log.tag.SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte DEBUG` on my test device. I use the same method to write out each log message at various points in the adapter's OnPerformSync() method, but often times isLoggable() is returning false. Below is a sample of my logcat, in which I added some error logging to show what was trying to be logged via a debug log when isLoggable() fails.

```
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: ====== PERFORMING SYNC ======
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: Inserted a set of data: 2379 rows
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: Inserted a set of data: 2292 rows
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: Inserted a set of data: 2241 rows
D/SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte: ====== TEST LOG MESSAGE ======
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: Inserted a set of data: 2382 rows
D/SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte: Inserted a set of data: 2503 rows
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: Inserted a set of data: 785 rows
E/LogHelper: TAG Not Loggable: SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte, Level: 3, msg: ====== SYNC POST-EXECUTE COMPLETE ======
```

All of the above messages are output in my OnPerformSync() method using a call the same logging method:

```
public void debug(String TAG, String message) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, message);
    } else {
        Log.e("LogHelper", "Not Loggable: " + TAG + ", Level: " + Log.DEBUG + ", msg: " + message);
    }
}
```

So why are some of the isLoggable() calls returning false, and others returning true? The `TAG`is the same (SB_ArchiveOrgSyncAdapte) in all calls to my `debug()`

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem.  Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG) returns "false" the first time I call it, and all subsequent calls seem to return "true".  Incredibly annoying.

Comment: I reported it as an AOSP bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220231